# Determining what button was clicked on form submit

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I need to mage a decision im my Spring MVC3 controller based on what button was clicked on the submit form. Now I have some idea how to do this, but Im not sure if its the best way.

I could use javascript to save parameter into hidden field and have this posted to my controller on submit and have this as parameter in my formBean.

It seems to me a little cumbersome. Is there a better way? Can I somehow figure out from request what button was clicked? Note I dont want to use ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the submit button used to submit the form will be a successful control.

So check the submitted value associated with the name you used for the submit buttons.

Comment: Right on I cans see the value of control I clicked. Thanx for reply.